# Необходимо поменять все повторяющиеся символы помимо первого

Tags: python

Получается поменять только все символы, хотелось бы понять что сделать чтобы все кроме первого, функция выведет oke****

```py
def fix_start(s):
    for i in s[:]:
        if s.count(i) >=2:
            c = s[:].replace(i,'*')
        else:
            c = s
    print(c)
    return

fix_start('okeyyyy')
```

Comment: Регулярками можно?

Answer (score 6):

Один из вариантов решения - хранить в множестве встретившиеся символы. Если очередной символ уже есть во множестве, то вместо него выводить *, иначе символ.

```
def fix_start(s):
    d, out = set(), ''
    for i in s:
        out += '*' if i in d else i
        d.add(i)
    return out

print(fix_start('okeyyyy'))
```

```
okey***
```

Comment: Лучше всё-таки не учить сразу плохому. `out` лучше сделать списком, который в конце склеивать в строку.

Comment: @CrazyElf прошу аргументы, почему "плохому"

Comment: Когда будете решать алгоритмические задачки на собеседованиях, тогда сразу поймёте )  Строки иммутабельны, каждое добавление в строку - это полное копирование исходной строки, т.е. алгоритм О(n) на ровном месте превращается в О(n^2).

Comment: @CrazyElf провел анализ производительности. Не так все очевидно, как оказалось - разместил новый ответ с результатами тестов и объяснениями

Answer (score 2):

Сравнение производительности вариантов решений:

1. +=
2. ''.join(list)
3. ''.join(generator)
4. просто +

```
import time

def fix_start1(s):
    print('Мой код (out+=):',end=' ')
    d, out = set(), ''
    for i in s:
        out += '*' if i in d else i
        d.add(i)
    return out

def fix_start2(s):
    print('Код со списком, предложенным @CrazyElf:',end=' ')
    d, out = set(), []
    for i in s:
        out.append('*' if i in d else i)
        d.add(i)
    return ''.join(out)

def fix_start3(s):
    def gen():
        hidden = set()
        for c in s:
            yield '*' if c in hidden else c
            hidden.add(c)
    print('Код @StanislavVolodarskiy с генератором:',end=' ')
    return ''.join(gen())

def fix_start4(s):
    print('Мой код, ухудшенный (out=out+...):',end=' ')
    d, out = set(), ''
    for i in s:
        out = out + '*' if i in d else i
        d.add(i)
    return out

test_string = 'a' * 10 ** 6
for fun in fix_start1,fix_start2,fix_start3,fix_start4:
    t = time.time()
    fun(test_string)
    print(time.time()-t)
```

Результаты:

```
Мой код (out+=): 0.17999768257141113
Код со списком, предложенным @CrazyElf: 0.10100007057189941
Код @StanislavVolodarskiy с генератором: 0.11700034141540527
Мой код, ухудшенный (out=out+...): 13.73800015449524
```

Лучший результат - со списком, предложенным @CrazyElf, второй - код @StanislavVolodarskiy с генератором, третий мой базовый `+=` (но проигрыш лидеру далеко не квадратичный, а примерно на 45%). Аутсадер - ухудшенный код, где конкатенация строк через `+`: проигрыш лидеру в 137 раз.
Очевидно, что для конкатенации строк оператор `+=` не то же самое, что `+`.
Шпаргалим, почему ... [находим](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4435752/15035314)(гуглоперевод):

> Если у вас есть только одна ссылка на строку и вы объединяете другую строку в конец, CPython теперь обрабатывает это как особый случай и пытается расширить строку на месте. Конечным результатом является то, что операция амортизируется O(n).

Comment: Хм, интересно, это с какой версии Питона такое? Так то известно, что `+=` это не тоже самое, что `= ... + ...`, но чтобы вот так... Я правда был уверен, что там копирование строк будет даже при `+=`, надо почитать на тему.

Comment: А вообще при разных размерах строк соотношение времени работы вариантов будет несколько разное, при некоторых размерах победит генератор или даже ваш изначальный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо! Я не знал про оптимизацию `+=`.

Answer (score 0):

Встреченные символы складываются в множество `hidden`. Строка строится генератором, без `+=`:

```
def fix_start(s):

    def gen():
        hidden = set()
        for c in s:
            yield '*' if c in hidden else c
            hidden.add(c)

    return ''.join(gen())


print(fix_start(input()))
```

> ```
> $ echo okeyyyy | py temp.py
> okey***
> ```

Comment: провел анализ производительности. Не так все очевидно, как оказалось - разместил новый ответ с результатами тестов и объяснениями

Answer (score 0):

Кому надо покороче, вот решение с `join` и списковым включением:

```py
def fix_start(string):
    return ''.join([s if s not in string[:i] else '*' for i, s in enumerate(string)])

print(fix_start('okeyyyy_bbb'))
```

Вывод:

```
okey***_b**
```

Comment: Это решение за квадрат. :(